# PHP eval - evaluate code that contains variables

Tags: php, eval

I'm building a module based CMS in which the admin can also create custom modules (along with predefined ones). Custom modules accept PHP code that will be evaluated when the module is displayed. Only the admin (single or plural) can edit this code, and only on the admin-page.* The script of the module is then stored in a database.

Let's say that, for example, a custom module is written in a way that it queries some information from the database - an older message to the management, if you will - into a variable, that is of course now user submitted data. Is it possible that this data will be somehow executed if it contains malicious php code? Or does eval handle variables the same way as it does with native PHP code?

I'm including an example, that the admin coded to list all user submitted messages.

**PHP code to be eval()'d**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT msg FROM messages;");

while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $message['msg'];
}
```

If one of the `$message['msg']` variables is `"; echo "you are screwed"; rmdir('root')`, will that be executed, or echoed?

---

*I know that the code can be edited by 'anyone' if the database is compromised, or if the code explicitly allows users to overwrite its contents, but it's strongly discouraged of course. I've left several warnings for these.

Comment: It is just as safe as if you had that code in a normal file. If it were that easy to screw PHP up, then you might have screwed it up just by asking your question :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I doubt stackoverflow answers are displayed using an evaluated script. I sincerely hope you are right, but I want to make sure. The above PHP code is not in a file, it's in a database. After being queried from the database, the script is evaluated, but in this case, it contains variables from untrusted user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you're just selecting and displaying the data... so the possibilities for attach is less...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT msg FROM messages;");

while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $message['msg'];
}
```

say if it is like...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT msg FROM messages where some=".$get/post-some.";");

while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $message['msg'];
}
```

theres possible attack of sql injection in `$getsome`like appending `'or 1=1'` at end or other types...

so you need to use `PDO` or `mysql_real_escape_string` while passing values... or just prepared statements...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm interested in is if there is an attack possibility coming _from_ the database that can somehow modify how the code is evaluated.

Comment: since you say that the code is modified only by authorized users the possibility is that anyone of them wants to crash the system for this to happen...